# ScriptableObjectInstaller не содержится в Zenject

Tags: c#, unity3d

Впервые щупаю Zenject. Если упустил очевидную вещь - прошу всё же разжевать.

В юнити нажал ПКМ -> Create -> Zenject -> ScriptableObjectInstaller. Был сгенерирован код, представленный почти без изменений на скрине (из изменений только подстановка `Zenject.` перед `ScriptableObjectInstaller`).

[image: Скрин]

Из любопытства я залез в исходники Zenject, где множество раз встретил нечто наподобие:

[image: Скрин]

Я понимаю, что студия не видит у меня в Zenject ScriptableObjectInstaller, но я не представляю, почему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в настройках [assembly definitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) .
Найдите assembly definition, которая относиться к папке куда вы кладете ваш `ScriptableObjectInstaller` и добавьте ему ссылку на `ZenjectAssembly`или перенесите `ScriptableObjectInstaller` в папку, где assembly definition уже позволяет использовать `ZenjectAssembly`.

PS: ну и код лучше прикладывать в виде текста :)

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло. Но в чём причина такого поведения zenject? Имею в виду, что неймспейс zenject же студия видит, даже без настроек assembly definitions

Comment: Assembly definitions в Unity к сожалению не очень дружат с IDE.